# Qt adding the compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I began to work with Qt but I already have a problem at the beginning .
I downloaded and installed qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_64-5.2.1.
Also I already have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express with SP1
When I tried to create a new project I got an error
[image]
but the program shows the compiler from VS but doesn't use it.
[image]
What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you selected qmake properly, too? Why are you mixing mingw and VS by the way? Also, I do not speak Russian, so I cannot understand the error message, although I can conclude from experience, but perhaps others cannot just yet.

Comment: Oh, and btw, why do you download the VS2012 version of Qt when you have the VS2010 installed? You need to find a matching version. Is this just a typo in your description or if not, it is a real problem that can cause this behavior.

Comment: I already downloaded and installed VS2012 Express and it solved the problem with the compiler, but instead I got a new problem with debugger because I don't have it and I can't find the way to add it in Qt Creator http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/374217d1394304959  http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/374218d1394304959t Is there any way to add the debugger ?

Comment: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-debugger-engines.html

Comment: I downloaded Windows 7 Standalone Debugging Tools (also for Windows XP) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365), installed it but I can't understand how to add the debugger in Creator. The debugger was installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugger > Add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, it seems that you have downloaded the VS2012 version of Qt, whereas you have VS2010 installed. This is not going to fly. You either need to install VS2012, or you will need to get a VS2010 built Qt version.

Also, it is better to avoid mixing mingw and Visual Studio, but this one is more like a tip.